# Sending udp broadcast from iPhone. Only works in a debugger mode. Not working when i install the same IPA

Tags: ios, networking, broadcast, gcdasyncudpsocket

Sending udp packets and listening data from the broadcast address using GCDAsyncudpSocket.
It is working fine when I run the application from the debugger mode from mac OS X Yosmite(Xcode -> device ipad air 8.2). It is not working when I install the IPA in the device.

Here is the following code I have used: 
****send****

```
 GCDAsyncUdpSocket * udpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    NSError *error = nil;

NSTimeInterval timeout= 1;
// Send the broadcast request, ie "Any upnp devices out there?"
char request[35];
request[0] = (Byte) 0xAA;
request[1] = (Byte) 0xAA;
request[sizeof(request)-2] = (Byte)0x55;
request[sizeof(request)-1] = (Byte)0x55;

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:request length:sizeof(request)];
UInt16 port=2918;
NSLog(@"begin scan");
if (![udpSocket bindToPort:port error:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Error binding: %@", error);
    return;
}
if (![udpSocket beginReceiving:&error])
{
     NSLog(@"Error receiving: %@", error);
    return;
}
if (![udpSocket enableBroadcast:YES error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error enableBroadcast: %@",error);
    return;
}
[udpSocket enableBroadcast:YES error: &error];
    [udpSocket setIPv4Enabled:YES];
    [udpSocket setIPv6Enabled:NO];
[udpSocket sendData :data toHost:[self getBroadcastAdress] port:port withTimeout:timeout tag:0];
```

**To receive :**

```
- (void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
      fromAddress:(NSData *)address withFilterContext:(id)filterContext
{
    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *host = nil;
    uint16_t port = 0;
    [GCDAsyncUdpSocket getHost:&host port:&port fromAddress:address];
    if(![host containsString:deviceIPAddress])
//    if ([host rangeOfString:deviceIPAddress].location == NSNotFound)
    {
            {
                if(![discoveredIPAddress contains Object:[[host componentsSeparatedByString:@":"] last Object]])
                    [discoveredIPAddress add Object:[[host componentsSeparatedByString:@":"] last Object]];
                N Slog(@"Printer IP: %@", discoveredIPAddress);

            }

}
}
```

Immediate help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What are the problem faces in release mode?